# Can New Account Contact Role value be added to a change set?

Tags: change-set

In my Sandbox, I have added a new type/value to the Account Contact Role (In the

> Setup->Customize->Accounts->Contact roles on account

).

How can I add that to the change set ?

Answer (score 2):

That field is not able to be migrated using a Change Set, as many of the standard fields on standard objects aren't.

You can use the Metadata API and the Force.com Migration Tool (Ant) to migrate that change.

There are third parties building on the Metadata API like Cloud9, MavensMate and [Gearset](https://gearset) (*full disclosure that I started Gearset...*) .

To move that field in Gearset takes about 10 clicks from your first visit to our site until successful deployment and we have a free 30-day trial with no lock in and no packages to install in your org. Use it for this and then never use it again if you so wish :)

[image: Gearset moving a picklist value]