# Extracting Metadata for Contact Role on Account

Tags: metadata-api, force.com-ide, custom-metadata

Can someone please share the package.xml to extract the MetaData for "Account Contact Role" or is it Unsupported Metadata type. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do/learn?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it can be deployed via the Metadata API using the [CustomField](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/customfield.htm) metadata type. The name will be AccountContactRole.Role.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>AccountContactRole.Role</members>
        <name>CustomField</name>
    </types>
    <version>37.0</version>
</Package>
```

Note that there was a change in [v38.0 to use StandardValueSet Names](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/standardvalueset_names.htm?search_text=AccountContactRole).

See also:

- [Can New Account Contact Role value be added to a change set?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/123182/102)
- Winter `17 Release Notes - [Streamlined Metadata API for Picklists](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter17/release-notes/rn_forcecom_picklists_new_api.htm)

Answer (score 0):

The new approach (API version 38.0 and later) to get/deploy this metadata is:

```
<types>
    <members>AccountContactMultiRoles</members>
    <name>StandardValueSet</name>
</types>
```

[Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/standardvalueset_names.htm)